# Install Python package located on Github

Tags: python-2.7, github, installation, package, anaconda

I'm trying to follow [this](http://pythonhosted.org/nolearn/convnet.html#installing-decaf-and-downloading-parameter-files) tutorial.
First step would be to install [DeCaf](https://github.com/UCB-ICSI-Vision-Group/decaf-release/).
I'm farely new to Python and so far I've only installed packages via easy_install, pip or Windows binaries.
How do I go about installing the DeCaf package? I tried downloading the ZIP from Github, and do a python setup.py install but it doesn't seem to work.
I'm on Windows 7, and use Anaconda 1.8.

Thanks,

G

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" - any more detail there?

Comment: "The System cannot find the path specified"
"Failed to build the C libraries; exiting"

Answer (score 5):

You can use the pip that ships with anaconda. Not sure that this library works on Windows as it requires c++ compiler with omp thread. From the anaconda terminal try:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/UCB-ICSI-Vision-Group/decaf-release.git
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following: 
i.e: installing ipdb package which is not there in anaconda list:

Following will try to install package from anaconda:

```
conda install ipdb
```

Following will show list of repo's from where you can install the package with versions:

```
anaconda search -t conda ipdb
```

Following will show more details about the package and repo:

```
anaconda show conda-forge/ipdb
```

Finally this will install the package from the repo:

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge ipdb
```